# Laravel 8 throwing NotFoundHttpException while accessing auth/login.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and am developing an application using Laravel 8. The application is returning NotFoundHttpException while accessing the login view. The issue is on the live web server, working fine on localhost. Other routes are working fine, like register and password reset. Auth::routes() is already in web.php. I think the issue is with the view path, which is (View: /home/hdipcom/hdip/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php) and it should be (View: /home/hdip/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php), highlighted in the attached image.

**LoginController.php**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        $type = Auth::user()->type;
        switch ($type) {
            case 'System':
                return '/admin';
                break;
            case 'Applicant':
                return '/applicant';
                break;
            default:
                return '/home';
                break;
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'status' => '1'
        ];
    }
}
```

[NotFoundHttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2M5n.jpg)

Comment: path `/home/hdipcom/hdip/resources/....` is correct or not?

Comment: Does your entire laravel project belongs to `/home/hdipcom/hdip` or `/home/hdip/` ?

Comment: the public folder path is  /home/hdipcom/public and other project path is /home/hdip/